# Modal no reproduce

Tags: jquery

Tengo un iframe cuando lo cerraba el seguía reproduciendo de fondo, le quité el atributo `src` y ya no sigue reproduciendo, pero cuando abro nuevamente el modal, no abre el iframe.

Este es el código:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#myModal").modal('hiden');
    var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');    

    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function()
    {
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');      
    });

    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal.m', function()
    {
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
    });
       $(".modal").click(function(){
        $('#cartoonVideo').removeAttr('src');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista el problema pareciera ser que te has equivocado en el nombre del evento `show.bs.modal.m`, el cual según al documentación es [`show.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

Intenta hacerlo así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal('hiden');
  var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');    

  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');
  });

  // AQUI - Nombre correcto del evento
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
  });
  
  $(".modal").click(function(){
    $('#cartoonVideo').removeAttr('src');
  });
});
```